# Following Code works in python interpreter but not as a script

Tags: python, linux, arduino, serial-port

I just made a tiny code to change the colors of my led strip in Linux too (I already did it in C# on Windows).

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.write(b'a')
```

When I type this into bash like this:

```
$sudo python2
>>>import serial
>>>ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
>>>ser.write(b'a')
1
```

it's working fine, but if I then execute the .py script like this:

```
$sudo python2 light.py
```

The ser.write part seems not to work. I dont get an err msg or anything. But I know that it's communicatin with the arduino cause the Onboard LED flashes when I execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got it, the Arduino resets after getting serial input, I just added a 3 Seconds delay before writing the Serial data